# Nifi communication with nifi-registry in restricted environments (http_proxy)

Tags: apache-nifi, http-proxy, apache-nifi-registry

I setup nifi and nifi-registry to different servers and they communicate fine with https and cert authorization and authentication.

Now i face a problem in exactly the same setup for another nifi that need to communicate with the same nifi-registry. The problem is that the new nifi is on a restricted area, with http_proxy. I search many days for a solution for that. I don't find anything in the documentation about that.
At nifi in the controller settings/registry-clients, is there any way that i can inform nifi that the communication will be through http_proxy and not straight?
Nothing on the documentation talks about that. Maybe people face it with another way? Or simple is not possible?

The version of nifi and nifi-registry are 1.15.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would probably need a clearer understanding of where the proxy is, but this page describes proxy configuration in front of NiFi and what fields that proxy would need to set to sit in front of NiFi: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.5.2/nifi-configuration-best-practices/content/proxy_configuration.html
and for NiFi registry:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/html/administration-guide.html#proxy_configuration

Comment: We don't have proxy in front of the nifi. The server that hosting our nifi have http_proxy env variable. So when we want to curl or wget something on this server we use 
https_proxy="1.1.1.1:xx" wget https:/..
Now from what i see when nifi try to communicate with the nifi-registry with public ip (since our nifi-registry is on another server), it timeout since i cannot give the option to use the http_proxy. The env variable https_proxy is set for the user that nifi is running. But unfortunately nifi do not use it and try to communicate without it. (On nifi, Controllersettings/registryclients)